# Unit test in java for method which catch exception and throw another modified exception

Tags: exception, mockito, testng, testng-eclipse

I am new with unit test. This is the first time I am writing unit test. I am trying to write Unit tests using TestNG framework.

```
class A {
   public Return_type method1(param1, param2) {
     for(var : tillSomeValue) {
       try {
         value = someMethod(var);
       } catch (someException ex) {
          /* do some calculation here with the value of thrown exception */
            throw anotherException();
         }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to write Unit tests for this class. Can some give me some leads?

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to test both scenarios - **success** ( a successful return value ) and **failures** ( Exception ) so name your methods accordingly.

Try to make success and failure scenarios from separate test methods.

```
testMethod1_success() { }
testMethod1_failure() { }
testMethod1_success_paramBoundaries() { }  etc etc
```

2. Your test method should try to communicate output of method / expected value as much as possible i.e. if its going to return a value 10 then that value should be fixed in test set up and communicate reasons for returning for that value.

Put `asserts` on expected value.

3. You need to write test methods for all possible logical paths and all permutations - combinations of input values - `param1 and param2`.

For better suggestions, do specify return type or parameter values of your method. You have not listed those.

This is what all I can think of in terms of **leads**, otherwise you can find good tutorials on Internet.